# How to calculate the volume of the lens created by the intersection of 2 spheres?

Tags: geometry, solution-verification

The centers of the spheres are 10 units apart.

$$R_1 = 8 \qquad R_2 = 4$$

I've come up with

$$64 = a^2 + r^2 \text{ and } 16 = b^2 + r^2 \Longrightarrow 10 = a + b$$

Therefore $a = 10 - b$, this leads to

$$64 = 100 - 20b + b^2 + r^2 \Longrightarrow 16 = b^2 + r^2$$

Leading to

$$b = 2.6 \quad a = 7.4 \quad r^2 = 9.24$$

From there $h_1 = 0.6$ and $h_2 = 1.4$

Following the formula $V = \dfrac{\pi h}{6} (3r^2 + h^2$) this gives the total volume

$V = \dfrac{\pi h_1}{6}(3r^2 + h_1^2) + \dfrac{\pi h_2}{6}(3r^2 + h_2^2)$

$V = \dfrac{\pi \cdot0.6}{6}(3\cdot9.24 + 0.6^2) + \dfrac{\pi \cdot 1.4}{6}(3\cdot9.24 + 1.4^2)$

Which results in $V \approx 30.58$

which is half of what the result should be.

[image]

Comment: I believe that the only error you have made is in assuming that given answer ("what the result should be") is correct.

Comment: I confirmed your calculation of $r^2,$ as well as $h_1$ and $h_2.$ So the entire lens fits within a cylinder of radius $3.03974$ and height $2,$ which has volume slightly less than $58.06.$ And a considerable part of the volume of that cylinder is outside the lens. So the lens must have volume quite a bit less than $58,$ certainly not twice $30.58.$